# Spliting the values inside an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some values in an object that are comma separated but stored in a field called "region" I want to be able to split the values on the comma and store the first one into a field called "city" and the second into a field call "place" I can only call the split method on string values so how could implement something like this on these kinds of values?

The code used :

```
 let entry = {
        ...list[i],
        phone_number: contact.phones.length > 0 ? contact.phones[0].number : "",
        region: entryData.summary.offer.delivery.summary[0].value.text || "",
        startingAt: entryData.summary.offer.publication.startingAt || "",
        endingAt: entryData.summary.offer.publication.endingAt,
        date: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
      };
```

Comment: Please show a Javascript object representation of what you're starting with and what you to end up with.  Also, I don't understand what the original content is that could be "comma delimited", but not a string?  What is that?

Comment: i have multiple values that look something like this : region : Gorzów Wlkp, woj. lubuskie i want the output to be something like this city : Gorzów Wlkp place : woj. lubuskie for all those values as for what am starting with am parsing json data that looks like this :
 `"entries": [
    {
        "name": "Lokalizacja",
        "content": "Gorzów Wlkp, woj. lubuskie",
        "icon": "icon-pin"
    }`

Comment: Apparently, someone else guessed the right answer, but next time please put the desired input and output data structure IN your question.

Comment: yes i will , thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
const loc = (entryData.summary.offer.delivery.summary[0].value.text || ",").split(',');
let entry = {
  ...list[i],
  phone_number: contact.phones.length > 0 ? contact.phones[0].number : "",
  city: loc[0],
  place: loc[1],
  startingAt: entryData.summary.offer.publication.startingAt || "",
  endingAt: entryData.summary.offer.publication.endingAt,
  date: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
};
```